# how to give box-shadow to the table data and its asp controls using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using table and an repeater in it to bind data,I want to highlight the table row by mouse hover and I wrote java script for that but here the problem is the table row is highlighting but when the mouse hover on asp controls the row is not highlighting

Answer (score 0):

Why javascript, look this css, it's pretty easy:

```
table.table-class tbody tr{transition: all 0.2s ease;-moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;-o-transition: all 0.2s ease;-ms-transition: all 0.2s ease;-webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;}
table.table-class tbody tr:hover{background:#ccc;color:#333;}
```

This will make the background of the tr to the color #333 with a animetion os 0.2 seconds.

Hope it helps